# How does AngularJS manage scope in ng-repeats?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I asked this question on programmers stackexchange a few days ago and didn't receive any replies, so I thought I'd try here.

I have a table that has around 60 rows and 20 columns. Each cell has a directive with an isolated scope. I use 2 nested ng-repeats to generate the table (one for rows and one for columns), but I'm wondering how angular handles scope when a digest cycle causes a re-generation of the directives in the ng-repeats?

Does it destroy all the previous isolated scopes in my directives and create new ones, or are those old isolated scopes now orphaned somewhere and memory leaking as more and more digests take place?

Is this something that I, as a developer, should be aware of and make sure to handle the destruction of any isolated scopes?

Comment: Each `ng-repeat` iteration creates a new scope. Each iteraton's scope is a sibling of another, and the directives' isolated scopes exist for the directive alone.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` creates a `$$hashKey` attribute in your `$scope` for all the values you are displaying. Whenever the `$digest` is called, it checks if the values changed or not. `ng-repeat` is usually one of the culprits in slow angular applications for multiple reasons.

1. You may not need to watch the variables. If you just want to show some data which doesn't get updated often you might as well remove the double-binding so angular doesn't have to create entries for them in the `$scope`
2. **Never** use a function result as a ng-repeat value because the function will run on every `$digest` cycle
3. Don't use filters since they get called twice in the `$digest` cycle and slow down the `ng-repeat`

[Here](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications)'s some more information about ng-repeat and angular performance.